# Can a not-Linux postgresql user create a database?

Tags: postgresql

`postgres` has created a postgresql user `foo`,

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser -d -P foo
Enter password for new role: foo
Enter it again: foo
```

Can `foo` create a database, let us say `foo`?

Comment: Run `psql -U foo` then run `create database`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createuser.html

> -d
>   --createdb
>   The new user will be allowed to create databases.

So as you have used the -d parameter the user foo should have the permission to [create databases](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html) like this:

```
createdb -h localhost -U foo foos_db
```

Comment: I know. I used that option. What is the command by which `foo` creates the database?